# Angularjs' app stop in some cases in IE11 but works when developer tools is open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

First of all, the code works fine at chrome and Firefox.
I tried and find that the problem is not console.log().
when i open the developer tools all works fine, but when i closed it the app stop in the middle of a scenario (there is an $http request in that scenario). but the app is responding, i can for example 'click' on a button or anything else, it's just that scenario that stop at the middle.
I'm trying to find exactly where is the problem - i tried to add 'window.alert' to some places - but again, when i added the 'window.alert' all worked fine again and i couldn't find the problem.

There is another option to find what is going there?

Comment: What is the link to Java?

Comment: What do you mean by a link to java?

Comment: You tagged this question as linked to Java, so I'm wondering what this has to do with Java.

Comment: Sorry, supposed to be javascript. Thanks - edited.